# How to make the conversation empty, when the tab is changed and the messages are empty

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a conversation section from particular user.
So, now if I make user from closed state to active state, the tab remains empty but the conversations are visible of the active part in the closed part.

My requirement works when it is refreshed.
So, now I want to make the conversations also to be empty,when there is no closed messages even before refresh.

HTML:

```
<div class="messageDiv" id="closedSection" *ngIf="closemessage && selectedTab == 1">
      <div class="headerSection">
        <div *ngIf="message_close != undefined">
          <img *ngIf="message_close != undefined" [src]="message_close.from_user_image || '../assets/images/msg.png'"/>
        </div>
        <div id="paragraph" *ngIf="message_close != undefined">
          <h3>{{message_close.from_user_name}}</h3>
          <p style="margin-top: -3.5%;margin-right: 24%;float: right;"><b>Date : </b> {{message_close.updated_at | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li *ngIf="message_close == undefined || message_close.messages.length == 0|| message_close.messages.length == undefined"> 
          <p>There is no closed messages.</p> 
        </li>
        <span *ngIf="message_close != undefined && message_close.messages.length > 0"> 
          <li *ngFor="let reply of message_close.messages">
            <img [src]="reply.from_user_image || '../assets/images/msg.png'"/>
            <p><b>{{reply.name}} </b> <span> {{reply.updated_at | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}} - {{reply.updated_at | date:'h:mm'}}</span></p>
            <p>{{reply.text}}</p>
          </li>
        </span>
      </ul>
      <button mat-mini-fab style="background-color: #a73036;position: absolute;margin-top: 60px;right: 5%;height: 50px;width: 50px;"><img src="../../../assets/images/navBar/message.png" alt="message" style="padding: 5px 5px 0px 9px;" (click)="addCloseMessages(message_close)"></button>
      <textarea placeholder="Reply..." [(ngModel)]="closedMessage"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Ts:

```
addCloseMessages(message_close) {
    if (!this.closedMessage || !this.closedMessage.trim()) {
      alert('Write a message');
      return;
    }
    var data = {
      text: this.closedMessage,
      to_user_id: message_close.from_user_id,
      proposal_id: message_close.proposal_id
    }
   this.service
       .sendMessage(data)
       .subscribe(
         response => {
           this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Successfully Added Message');
           this.closedMessage = '';
           this.loadMessages();
           this.changeTab();   
        }, error => {
           this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Failed to add Message');
        });
 }
```

Comment: share thefunction where you change the tab

Comment: this.changeTab function

Comment: changeTab() {
    this.selectedTab = 0;
    this.closemessage = false;
  }

Comment: share your html which you want to hide when tab change
share your code in your question by editing it

Comment: <span *ngIf="message_close != undefined && message_close.messages.length > 0"> 
          <li *ngFor="let reply of message_close.messages">
            <img [src]="reply.from_user_image || '../assets/images/msg.png'"/>
            <p><b>{{reply.name}} </b> <span> {{reply.updated_at | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}} - {{reply.updated_at | date:'h:mm'}}</span></p>
            <p>{{reply.text}}</p>
          </li>
        </span>

Comment: edit your question and share full html there so i can find which your active part and which is your closed part then i can solve your qusetion

Comment: when you want to make conversation empty means when on active part or close part

Comment: its in close part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you refresh the page, at that time conversation will be clear but when you just change the tab at that time conversation will not clear,
means from database side your conversation cleared but from html side not,

according to your shared html message_close is object to show your conversation so, to clear close part you have to set it to undefined then your issue will be solved, so clear html by setting undefined to message_close in you changeTab function like below,

```
changeTab() {   
this.selectedTab = 0;   
 this.closemessage = false;
this.message_close = undefined;//this will clear your html without refresh

 }
```

Comment: ya but do i need to change anything in html?

Comment: html works fine but the message_close variable not cleared when you change the tab so, I have set it to undefined it will solved your issue